# Nakattan -- what does n mean?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I've heard a few times a word "nakattan" with n at the end. I know what nakatta mean, what does N mean?

Comment: Was it said by a Kansai dialect speaker? Do you have the context?

Comment: @chocolate, I don't know. I've also heard it in a lesson for beginners.

Comment: Was part of a larger phrase, like "nakatta n desu ka?"

Comment: @snailplane, in one case yes, in others i don't remember.

Answer (score 1):

ん is usually the short of の verbally。

In your case it could become なかったの, which means to emphasize it was not there or to ask if it was there.

Comment: 「なかった**な**の」<- You meant to type なかったの, right?

Comment: Oopsie. I edited it. (Can I blame the auto-correct?)